# How to silence Xcode warning: "variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]"?

Tags: c++

I am very confused by the format of Xcode, and have tried to look around to by advice: "invert the flag" that shows up when we get these warnings. If someone could walk me through how to get to that page to silence this warning. I would be VERY grateful :)

Comment: you cannot use variable length arrays in c++..

Comment: Re: `How to silence` - don't use them, they are not standard

Comment: The best way is to remove variable length arrays. Go to your source code and replace the VLAs with `std::vector`

Comment: Closely related: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) I'm waffling over whether or not I should dupe-hammer, so I'll punt.

Comment: @user4581301 agreed.

Comment: C++ does not support C99's variable length arrays.  Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use variable-length arrays. They are not a part of standard c++, and you should use a `std::vector` instead.

However, if you want to turn off a specific warning such as `-Wvla-extension` then you can explicitly suppress this warning by adding the `-Wno-vla-extension` flag when compiling the program.

You can add this flag to wherever you would normally put such flags in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to NOT use VLAs (variable Length Arrays) because they are out of the standard and unsafe, but if necessary, you can use

```
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-name"
```

Replace `warning-name` with the warning name to silence

I assume that you are using clang, but if you are using GCC, replace `clang` with `GCC`.

Here is a link may also be help:

https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/12/15/silencing-specific-build-warnings/